# FinOps :: what is the best cloud monitoring tool for costs?

Tags: cloud-service, cloud-storage, finance, cloud, azure

Our infrastructure is on Azure and costs are spiking mainly driven by Azure SQL Database and App Services.

I know there are a lot of monitoring tool that could help me out with [database monitoring](https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/sql-server-monitoring-tools/) (Red-Gate, SolarWinds, Sentry One, etc...).

Is there a software that could help me out monitoring performances of **App Services**?

Is there a software that could help me out monitoring performances of **App Services** and **Azure SQL Database**?

(No, the Azure dashboard isn't enough)

Answer (score 0):

I want to reply to my question.

I searched for the word `FinOps` in the Azure search bar and I found these 6:

[image]

I'm now going to test https://cloudmonitor.ai/